# Can I dynamically apply a drop-down (select) box to the swagger using Go?

Tags: go, swagger, fibers

I'm using Swagger UI with Fiber in Go. As far as I know, Swagger can configure array [string] in this way. The current form requires entering enum in advance, and I want to add it as a script. Is there a way?

Can I dynamically add Swagger UI parameters scheme in the Go script?

[image]

```
paths:
  /test:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: tag
          schema:
            type: string
            default: none
            enum:
              - available
              - pending
              - sold
```

Comment: "The current form requires entering enum in advance, and I want to add it as a script. Is there a way?" -- what do you mean by this?

Comment: For example, you must enter an enum value in advance to create the select box.  I added a script to the text above.
(must enter it directly into swagger.yaml.)